# What is the meaning of "Right, ten digits round the blunt bit. Give it a tug. Left foot, right foot."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Arthur going to draw a sword which in stuck in rock. David Beckman, Soldier from Vortigern kingdom. David Beckham giving the instructions how to draw it.

> **Right, ten digits round the blunt bit. Give it a tug. Left foot, right
>   foot**. Collect your brand. Back on the barge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's take things in order.

1) **Right** This is short for "All right", a general term of encouragement.

2) **ten digits around the blunt bit** Sticking out of the rock is the sword, consisting of blade and hilt. The blade is sharp, while the hilt is not, and blunt is an antonym of sharp. Fingers are also called digits, and you have ten of them, five on each hand. So grab hold of the hilt with both hands.

3) **Give it a tug** To tug an object, or give it a tug, is to pull on it. So pull the sword out of the stone.

4) **Left foot, right foot** This is the process of walking - you put your left foot forward, then your right, and repeat as necessary. So take the sword and show it to whoever you need to.

So a paraphrase might be, **Here's what you need to do. Grab the sword. Pull it out of the rock. Collect your reward.**

Comment: I'd put the paraphrase as "Grab the sword by the hilt with both hands."

Comment: Just a quick note (having seen the film recently) "Collect your brand" is an instruction to be branded with a hot iron so that it is clearly visible that he has made an attempt to pull the sword from the stone. I would not personally call this "receiving a reward". Also Arthur is not expected to succeed, as the soldiers are searching for the one in a million who can pull the sword. A better paraphrase might be "Here's what you need to do. Grab the sword. Try to pull it out of the rock. Get your skin branded to show that you tried".

Comment: @Drgabble , since you've seen it recently: I'm guessing that "left foot, right foot" is actually the speaker illustrating a proper sword-pulling stance (*placement* of each foot) -- is that the case?   (As opposed to referring to walking, but without the extra context that's a good guess as well)

Comment: @AC either interpretation is valid there I think. My feeling would be that it is a reference to walking, particularly as the branding tent was a few tens of metres or so away, implying distance that needs to be traversed.